# Sharing properties down from parent when using Angular 2 routing

Tags: angular

I am attempting to use Routing in Angular2 having previously used the inclusion of components directly in the parent app using their custom tags and then using properties to show/hide components depending on the app state. For this, I was able to use the below code :

```
constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => AppComponent)) app : AppComponent) {
    ...
}
```

This got messy quickly however and I am now using routing. The code now breaks  when I add the @Inject parameter to the constructor with the following error:

```
EXCEPTION: Cannot resolve all parameters for Profile(@Inject(undefined)). Make sure they all have valid type or annotations.
```

How would I go about passing the state of the parent to the children in this case? I need to do this as the parent controls the state of whether the user is logged in or not which drives the visibility of parts of the UI. Is it possible to pass parameters into the  tag and access that from the actual component?

Alternatively, how could I go about ensuring all components can detect the login state if not directly being passed down from the parent application?

Comment: are you looking for stateparams like angular1 ? by using this you can pass the values via routing and get in the other components.

Comment: @Pardeepjain I considered route-params but I'd rather hide these away from the URL if possible and have a property passed between the parent and child components behind the scenes

Comment: i don't think so that there is any other option available by using which you can hide these from URL. btw i have found good tutorials for stateperams in angular2 link is here. i hope it will help you. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/cheatsheet.html

Comment: As for now it's not possible to pass properties from parent to children when `<router-outlet>` is between them, see [#4452](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4452)

Comment: Thank you very much both for your help.